# Update Angular Record

Tags: php, mysql, angular, typescript, rxjs

For some reason my mind is wrapping around what the problem is here. I am using Angular with a PHP mysql database. I have done console.log for basically every step of the way and it seems to be working, but the textboxes won't display the information that is already inserted into the database.

This form appears when the update button is pressed:

```
<div *ngIf="this.isClubEditVisible">
  <form #f = "ngForm">
  <br><br><br>
  {{ account.account_type }}
  <label>Club Name  </label>
  <input type="text" name="school_name" class="form-control input-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectedAccount.account_type" placeholder="Full School Name" autocomplete="off">
  <br><br>
  <h3>Contact Information</h3>
  <label>Contact Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="contact_name" class='form-control input-sm' [(ngModel)]="selectedAccount.contact_name" placeholder="John Doe">
  <br><br>
  <label>Contact Email  </label>
  <input type="text" name="contact_email" class="form-control input-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectedAccount.contact_email" placeholder="name@example.com">
  <br><br>
  <label>Contact Phone Number  </label>
  <input type="text" name="contact_number" class="form-control input-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectedAccount.contact_number" placeholder="(000) 000-0000">
  <br><br>




  <input type="button" (click)="update(f)" class="btn btn-success" value="Update Account">
  <input type="button" (click)=" cancel()" class="btn btn-cancel" value="Cancel">
  </form> 
</div>
```

This report is initiated by the update button which also calls a function to define what record to edit in the database.

```
<table border='0' width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
  <tr *ngFor="let Account_Info of account; let i = index">
    <button (click)="selectPolicy(account);this.isClubEditVisible = true;" class="nav-delete" type="button">Edit Account Information</button>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the function called by the edit button

```
selectPolicy(account: Account_Info){
    console.log("selected account");
    this.selectedAccount = account;
    console.log(this.selectedAccount);
  }
```

When I print out the selected account in the console it shows the array correctly. Then I thought the textboxes should update above to display the information correctly. But the textboxes are null. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `Account_Info` and how do you update ? Is this an array and you `push` items ?

Comment: @Marco yes its an array that is declared at the top of the script `account: Account_Info[];` and then also `selectedAccount: Account_Info = {id: null, school_name: null, account_type: null, admin_gpa: null, admin_sat: null, admin_act: null, merit_gpa: null, merit_sat: null, merit_act: null, in_tuition: null, out_tuition: null, service_academy: null, school_icon: null, school_type: null, contact_email: null, contact_name: null, contact_number: null };` I'm importing Account_Info from a ts file `import { Account_Info } from '../account_info';` which just has all of the columns declared

Comment: From my understanding all seems ok... Could you try to change default values from `null` to empty string `""` ?

Comment: @Marco for some reason the problem is that the textboxes are hidden and then are set to visible using *ngIf. I couldn't figure out a solution, so instead I just made them always visible and the boxes are updated on init. Then if I don't need to see them I hide the boxes.

Comment: Try to put the `this.isClubEditVisible = true;` instruction in the `selectPolicy function`.